# Proof of Correctness of Bottleneck Dijkstra Algorithm

Tags: ds.algorithms, proof-complexity, correctness

I am working on a bottleneck multicast tree for which I am using bottleneck Dijkstra algorithm.

My question is 1) bottleneck Dijkstra has the same correctness as that of (simple) Dijkstra or not ?

2) if yes then how and if no then how?

Will be happy to see your responses. Thank you

Comment: This is probably better on cs.se.